# form inside a div is not properly aligning

Tags: css, forms, html, alignment

I have a form inside a  that no matter what I do it aligns left into the sidebar. I had it working properly a while back and changed something now I can't get it to go back to the center.

Here is the link where I am testing everything.

http://amfotography.com/newsite/contact.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a `margin-left` to make up for the offset of your fixed side bar:

Example:

```
#form{
   margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Comment: My css looks like this

#form {
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 color:#ffffff;
 width:30em;
 margin-left:300px;
 margin-top:100px;
}

Comment: Well according to web developer tools, it's not being applied due rogue characters. Fix your those characters and you're golden.

Comment: I have been through the css top to bottom and cannot find any rogue characters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some strange characters after #liston

```
#liston {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #d00101;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:left;
    }â <================== here
#form {
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color:#ffffff;
    width:30em;
   margin:auto;
}
```

When I remove those, it works fine (you still need to set the margin: auto to margin-left: 200px)

Comment: I see these faulty characters when I view with the webdeveloper plugin (http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) in Firefox. I guess loading your CSS file in an editor such as Notepad++, might make them visible. Just remove them, save the file again, and give it a try.